# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. I have the key but the error remains

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, key

I am trying it iterate through an array with the map function. I have the key property on the children. I am still getting the error ```Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'''.
When I comment out the rating property in the objects, in my array, the error goes away. The rating property is used in the 'rating' function to create a 'star rating' with an svg image. The ratings function is called in the JSX, within the map function.

```js
const Reviews = () => {
  const reviews = [
    {
      id: 1,
      rating: 3,
      image: "/images/reviews/one.jpg",
      name: "Adam Jarod",
      jobTitle: "Sales manager",
      review:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur necessitatibus voluptatem aliquid alias quia beatae non quidem dolore praesentium",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      rating: 4,
      image: "/images/reviews/two.jpg",
      name: "Emily Rees ",
      jobTitle: "Marketing Specialist",
      review:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur necessitatibus voluptatem aliquid alias quia beatae non quidem dolore praesentium",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      rating: 5,
      image: "/images/reviews/three.jpg",
      name: "John Smith",
      jobTitle: "Office Assistant",
      review:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur necessitatibus voluptatem aliquid alias quia beatae non quidem dolore praesentium",
    },
  ];
  
  const ratings = (review) => {
    let stars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < review.rating; i++) {
      stars.push(React.createElement("img", { src: "/images/star.svg" }));
    }
    return stars;
  };

  return (
    <section className="reviews">
      <h2 className="subtitle">What our clients say</h2>
      <h1 className="title">Reviews</h1>
      <div className="reviews__cards">
        {reviews &&
          reviews.map((review) => {
            return (
              <div key={review.id} className="review-card">
                <div className="avatar-name">
                  <div className="avatar">
                    <img src={review.image} alt="Client" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="name">
                    <h1>{review.name}</h1>
                    <h2>{review.jobTitle}</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className="quote-icon"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="review-body">
                 <div className="review-body__rating">{ratings(review)}</div>
                  <div className="review-body__text">
                    <p>{review.review}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              
            );
          })}
           <div className="reviews__nav-buttons">
                  <div className="left-arrow">
                  <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  strokeWidth="1.5"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  className="w-6 h-6"
                >
                  <path
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                    d="M19.5 12h-15m0 0l6.75 6.75M4.5 12l6.75-6.75"
                  />
                </svg>
                  </div>
                  <div className="right-arrow">
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      strokeWidth="1.5"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      className="w-6 h-6"
                    >
                      <path
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        d="M4.5 12h15m0 0l-6.75-6.75M19.5 12l-6.75 6.75"
                      />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a string instead of a number for your id, such as:

```
{
  id: "mykey_1",
  rating: 3,
  image: "/images/reviews/one.jpg",
  name: "Adam Jarod",
  jobTitle: "Sales manager",
  review:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur necessitatibus voluptatem aliquid alias quia beatae non quidem dolore praesentium",
},
```

Comment: I tried making it strings. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

the images you create in `ratings` don't have a key.
Try changing to something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < review.rating; i++) {
      stars.push(React.createElement("img", { src: "/images/star.svg", key: i }));
}
```